# Creating truth table

Tags: digital-logic, opto-isolator, truth-table

I want to create a truth table to see all options for 74HC123 output. Basically an optocoupler output is connected to 74HC123 as input. 74HC123 will get the data from optocoupler. There could be two options "0" and "1".

Optocouple has 1 output and 74HC123 has 3 inputs. So i wanted to create truth table to see options for output data.

I did something like this:

[image]

74HC123 truth table:

[image]

Is it true? If it is wrong, how can i do it?

Comment: If you compare your table to datasheet table, they don't match. Just use datasheet table.

Comment: @Justme what's wrong with mine ? All i did was giving nA,nB and nRD "0" and "1".

Comment: That is exactly the problem. The chip does nothing interesting when inputs are stable, i.e. not changing. The datasheet table shows how the chip reacts to changing inputs.

Comment: @Justme Can you please give me an example about part of changing and not changing inputs?

Comment: \$\uparrow\$ is an example of a changing input: LOW-to-HIGH transition. For this you have to consider the _previous_ and _current_ state of the signal.

Comment: Definitely wrong, I can assure you of that. More specifically "x" definitely does not imply a Low signal, if it did they would put a 'L' instead of the x which is 'don't care' (high or low). This can be confusing I understand. But this is why they attach superscripts to the outputs on the datasheet. This clarifies any confusion. Which is where I think your interpretation is going wrong. The arrows are also not indicative of a high or low state, rather a transition/change from one state to the other.

Comment: Why do you think yours is correct?  They have 3 states that cause pulses.  You have 1.  That seems incorrect.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat i didn't say mine was correct. I wanted to know if it's correct or not. I'm trying to do it in correct way.

Comment: @lightweightmcgee Probably i didn't explain myself clearly. What I'm trying to do is giving "0" and "1" to inputs of 74HC123 and find the output. There are 3 inputs so possibilities are 2x2x2 = 8. And find the output for each input states.

Comment: @Bowman maybe I need to clarify myself. This is not a decoder/encoder where you can map out the states the way you are trying.  Better yet I should simply say, this is not something you can make a truth table for but rather an "excitation table" I suppose.. They aren't fixed states rather conditions that need to be met, to get a specific output. I know that sounds like it means the same things, believe me it does not.

Comment: Semantics.  They have 3 states that cause pulses. You have 1. That is incorrect.

Comment: Even in the static cases you have an error. The data sheet says while nRD is L/0 and nA and nB anything, the outputs Q and nQ are 0 and 1, respectively, but your table lists "none" for nRD=0 and nA/nB=1.